# window.scroll jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

HI friends I just want to get window `scrollTop()` with below mentioned function but its not working I dont know why

Please check **[fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/sdcoxL6h/)** or you can check code below

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$(window).scroll(function(){
   var top = $(this).scrollTop();
  });

)}
```

Comment: its working http://jsfiddle.net/sdcoxL6h/1/

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p><p>s</p>

<input type="button" value="top" name="top" id="btnTop">
```

jquery:

```
$('#btnTop').on("click",function(){
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow', function () {
                      alert("reached top");
                    });
});
```

Updated : http://jsfiddle.net/sdcoxL6h/4/